# Convert SQL statement to Linq-to-SQL with 2 columns with a count(*) not working

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have a SQL statement that I need to convert to Linq-to-SQL.

The SQL statement that works is

```
Select 
    Comment, count(*) as counted 
from 
    [ESO].[ESO].[DOCCCOIssues] 
group by 
    comment
```

Linq I have an issue with

```
var issueModel = new IssuesModel();

var query = (from c in DOCCCOIssues//.IssuesModels
            //group c by c.Comment into g
            select new
            {
                c.Comment,
                //Count = g.Count()
            });
```

1. I know how to specify a bunch of fields
2. I did comment out an example i saw of someone doing a group by  with a count -  not sure how to get this to work
3. I have seen the linq queries of ONLY getting `select c).Count()`, and that is not want I want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you have done the group by you have a list where each entry is iself an `IEnumerable` of the things in each group and has a `Key` property (the thing you grouped on, in this case `Comment`). See [Group Elements in a Sequence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386922(v=vs.110).aspx) on MSDN.

So in your result, you just need to return the `Key` as the Comment and then the `Count()` in that grouping, as you already tried:

```
var query = (from c in DOCCCOIssues//.IssuesModels
            group c by c.Comment into g
            select new
            {
                Comment = g.Key,
                Count = g.Count()
            });
```

[Working .NetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LscsHm)